# Jawr with plain html

Tags: html, jawr

For some reason I didn't use JSP in my JAVA project and I only use plain html. Now I want to use jawr bundle files in my plain html, as I have searched, it should include a jawr_loader.js as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jawr_loader.js" ></script>
        <script>
                JAWR.loader.style('/bundles/all.css');
                JAWR.loader.script('/bundles/global.js');
        </script>
```

I don't know if there is a jawr_loader.js already exist or I need to create one. If I need to create one, what the content I should write in the file,
Sorry maybe this problem is too stupid, but I new to java project using jawr, and I look for solution for few days but still cannot find answer, plz help me, thx.